# Cyrillic characters in Apache POI excel file hyperlink address

Tags: scala, character-encoding, apache-poi

I use Scala and Apache POI (with [folone/poi-scala](https://github.com/folone/poi.scala)).

I want to create a hyperlink to the local file in the cell. The path of the file contains cyrillic characters. And in Excel i can't open this file, i see '?' instead of cyrillic characters.
I tried to go through a lot of encodes and URL encoding, but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
...
val cell = sheetOne.asPoi.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0)
cell.setHyperlink({
    val link = new HSSFHyperlink(HSSFHyperlink.LINK_FILE)
    link.setAddress("D:/Проверка/проверка.txt")
    link
})
...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to replace

```
HSSFHyperlink.LINK_FILE
```

by

```
HSSFHyperlink.LINK_URL
```